# What are the methods to run existing application and upgraded application together in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an application completely created on .net 4.6. Now I am going to do a tech upgrade of the project as .net 5 web API with angular.

**Situations**

- .net 4.6 project is in live.
- Do not going to wait for completely upgrade entire project into new(.net 5) and deploy. If new requirement comes it will be added into this upgraded version and not going to do the same in existing project.
- I completed one module (e.g. user creation)of tech upgrade project.

**Questions**

So is it possible to run the upgraded module(.net 5 with angular) with the existing application(.net 4.6)?

That means I can be login in application and for the user creation portion should be work in new updated thing but remaining modules are working in the old. That is replace the user module with new upgraded so next time I will complete the another module and replace it and so on.
How can I achieve this?

How can I run parallel with updates?

What are the major things to be noted?

There is one way may possible that host the applications as sub domains and then redirect the user module. I want to know is there any other ways to achieve it and what are the complexities in this situation?

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/incremental-migration-strategies

Comment: best to bite the bullet now.  Migrate the whole project.  You'll find that much is backwards compatible with .net4.6.  (and you can eliminate a lot of packages cause they'll all be there in the core) You can target ".netstandard2" to use both, but personally I'd tackle it all at once.  See the table here for compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: ..when I say "core" that might be confusing because MS decided to drop "-core" from the name, but ".net5" is really "asp.net-core4", but they skipped 4 and dropped the "-core".  (In general .net terminology is extremely confusing to me... I just now learned that .net5 is actually the latest -core... and I'd just upgraded from asp-net-core2.2 to asp-net-core3.1... now I've got to go to .net5 when I should have done that to begin with..)

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, the doc is very useful for the topic.

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins, Migrating slice by slice is the method which I am looking for and it is described in the doc shared by DavidBrowne-Microsoft. And when it say about the Support to .net core 3.1 will be end on December 2022 and the latest .net5 support also will end after 6 months once .net6 come. So for terminology wise as you said its little bit confusing.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft By doing slice by slice migration how can we handle the session in the 4.6 project and token authentication in .net 5 API?